# SQL Join issue returning NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am having trouble running a query over three tables:

users, user_teams, user_messages

I wish to create a report where a line manager can see the total for incoming mail and outgoing mail for all members of their team.  The query is to show zero values for a user if there are no outgoing or incoming.

My tables are as follows:

```
users
------
uid
forename
surname

user_teams
-------------
id
manager_id
member_id

user_messages
-------------
id
outgoing
incoming
uid
msg_date
```

Both manager_id and member_id relate to the uid field of users.  There is a one to many relationship between managers and users.

My query so far is this:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.forename, u.surname,
SUM(IF(m.outgoing=0 ,1,0)) AS total_outgoing,
SUM(IF(m.incoming>0 ,1,0)) AS total_incoming,
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_messages m
ON m.uid=u.uid AND m.msg_date>='2012-09-01' AND m.msg_date<='2013-08-31'
RIGHT JOIN user_teams ut ON ut.member_id=u.uid
WHERE ut.leader_id=?
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY u.surname ASC
```

This functions correctly if a user has either sent or received a message.  However, if the SUM for both fields is zero, I recieve NULL for uid, forename and surname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN user_messages m` insted `INNER JOIN user_messages m` When there is no messages it's normal that you are getting  (NULL for uid, forename and surname).

Answer (score 0):

use COUNT instead of SUM or add an IFNULL clause to the select on outgoing and incoming.